# OutOfMemoryException handling and Windows Media Player SDK

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, wmplib

How it must work:

```
WindowsMediaPlayer windowsMediaPlayer = new WindowsMediaPlayer(); 
IWMPMediaCollection collection = windowsMediaPlayer.mediaCollection;
IWMPMedia newMedia = collection.add(path);  //causes OutOfMemoryException after some thousands  method's iterations
```

I've tried to avoid it this way:

```
try
{
    newMedia = collection.add(path);
    return newMedia;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    collection = null;
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    WindowsMediaPlayer windowsMediaPlayer = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
    IWMPMediaCollection collectionNew = windowsMediaPlayer.mediaCollection;
    return CreateNewMedia(collectionNew, path);
}
```

But this does not work – I still get infinite exception loop inside `catch`.

Comment: A stack trace would be useful

Comment: This is inside the `CreateNewMedia` method? So the operation throws an `Exception` and you are recursively retrying it again? Why would it work the nth time if it failed the first time?

Comment: Yes, it's a loop. Execution failed at more than 2000 time. So I tried to free memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can not handle `OutOfMemoryException` like ordinary one. The reason you may have handling that, is just, in some way, to save the state of application, in order to provide to the consumer of your application a way to recover lost data. 
What I mean is that there is no meaning calling `GC.Collect` or whatever, cause application is going to dead *anyway*, but `CLR` kindly give you notification about that before.

So to resolve this issue, check the memory consumption of your application, that on `32bit` machine has to be something about `1.2GB` of RAM, or control the quantity of the elements in collections you have, that can not exceed, for ordinary list, 2GB of memory on 32bit **and** on 64bit too.